# unable to use array element

Tags: php, sql

The below code is supposed to get latitude and longitude and produce the full address(street,city,country) of where a person is living. All of that is successful but when I use the explode function on the address and put the data into array elements. I can't get data from each individual element. Note: I used echo on each array element and they output fine to the screen. 
This is the error I am getting :Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in C:\wamp\www\bloodonation\geosendmail.php on line 36
and Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\bloodonation\geosendmail.php on line 37. Line 36 & 37 are the ones after the explode function. I want the value of $city to use in the sql query. Please help me. What am I missing. This is the data from the echo: Habbal Beirut Lebanon. I want the city which is Beirut to use in my sql query

```
    $address= getaddress($latitude,$longitude);
$multiple= explode(',',$address);
$parseaddress = $multiple[0]; // address   
$city = $multiple[1]; // city
$country = $multiple[2]; // country

// getting a persons email
//$to;

//Take contents of the search box
//mail function parameters, send two sets of messages depending on blood/organ donation
  //create a temp file in bloodonation and take the name from there,then delete the temp file

    $firstname=$_SESSION["firstname"];
    $fathername=$_SESSION["fathername"];
    $lastname=$_SESSION["lastname"];
    $query ="SELECT email,bloodoner,organdoner,bloodtype,bodytype
        FROM personprofile
        WHERE   firstname= '$firstname' AND lastname= '$lastname' AND fathername= '$fathername'";
        $fetchemail=  mysqli_query($link,$query);
        $process=mysqli_fetch_assoc($fetchemail);

        $pbloodtype="SELECT personprofile.bloodtype,personprofile.firstname,personprofile.lastname,personprofile.fathername,hospital.hospitalname
        FROM personprofile,hospital,areaname 
        WHERE areaname.id= hospital.area AND personprofile.hospitaladmission= hospital.id AND areaname.area='$city'";
```

Comment: Obligatory "your code is vulnerable to SQL injection" comment here. Please do not inject values directly into queries. Use parameters instead.

Comment: What’s the output if you do echo “<pre>”;die(print_r($multiple));  right after the explode?

Comment: Sounds like `$multiple` does not contain what you think it does. Take @GlenElkins advise to see what it really contains.